# multiple gulp tasks with different js files

Tags: angularjs, gulp

Give a small example on the multiple gulp tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a folder with 'gulp' and add your gulp tasks inside that.

*gulp.js*

```
var wrench       = require('wrench');

wrench.readdirSyncRecursive('./gulp').filter(function(file) {
  return (/\.(js)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function(file) {
  require('./gulp/' + file);
});
```